# как исправить : curl_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

Tags: php, curl

Я пытаюсь получить записи с другого сервера базы данных через API и отправить их в форму. Все работает нормально, дело в том, что я получаю это предупреждение (curl_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given). Мой код выглядит следующим образом:

```
<?php
    curl_exec($ch);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
    require('/home/users/m/xxx/domains/xxx.ru/a.php');
    require('/home/users/m/xxx/domains/xxxy.ru/b.php');
    if ($just_phone)
    {
            if($key)
            {
            echo "yes";
            if($request_params)
            {
                $request_params='{"form_id": 511175,"fields":[{"id":4,"value":'.$just_phone.'},{"id":23,"value":"'.date('Y-m-d', time()-10800).'T'.date('H:i', time()-10680).':00Z"},{"id":6,"value":"'.date('Y-m-d', time()-10800).'T'.date('H:i', time()-10680).':00Z"}]}';
            }
            }
        else {
            
        }
    }
    curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В соответствии с [документацией PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-exec.php) перед вызовом `curl_exec` следует инициализировать $ch коммандой `curl_init`:

```
<?php
// создание нового cURL ресурса
$ch = curl_init();

// установка URL и других необходимых параметров
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// загрузка страницы и выдача её браузеру
curl_exec($ch);

// завершение сеанса и освобождение ресурсов
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вызвать сначала `curl_init` и полученный ресурс передавать в `curl_exec`.